# What methods are used to breakdown an EM wave into different frequencies?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

What are the methods that are used to breakdown an EM wave into different frequencies?

Comment: Might [electronics.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: @KyleKanos  , well, I was considering the electronics SE before the physics SE , but i wanted the physicists breakdown of a complex EM wave into different frequencies

Comment: Well you might want to consider editing your question to reflect the physics aspect, as you've got several [close votes](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) for engineering reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quadrature amplitude modulation (QAM). In the simplest form it works as follows

The incoming signal is multiplied by either a sine (or cosine) to get the quadrature (or in phase) component of the signal.

Now there are two amplitude modulated signals (the quadrature and in phase) which both use amplitude-shift keying (ASK) to encode data. The simplest form of ASK is two level (on or off) and it works as follows

The incoming signal is rectified (like taking the absolute value) then low pass filtered (to remove the high frequency and just see the on and off). Then you are left with DC levels representing 0 or 1.

In practice wireless routers use many more phases than 0 and 90 and many more amplitudes than on or off but the principle is the same. For example wireless N uses 16-QAM which has 12 different phases and 4 different amplitudes to encode 16 bits.

Comment: This would be a lot easier to understand with a block diagram and equations to illustrate what is described in the words.

Comment: Maybe you could make one then?